# Importing SpacyTextBlob shows Attributeerror

Tags: python, spacy, attributeerror, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to import the **SpacyTextBlob** to do some unsupervised sentiment analysis. I installed and load the package as:

```
pip install spacytextblob --user
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob
```

But it shows `AttributeError: type object 'Language' has no attribute 'factory'`.

I have searched the issue and found [this](https://github.com/R1j1t/contextualSpellCheck/issues/53). I tried to do

```
!pip install contextualSpellCheck
```

But that installation also failed. I am using python 3.8 and spacy 2.3.7. Is it any comapaitibility issue or the command has been changed? Is there anyone else who faced the same and know the workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the workaround. The issue is the compatibility of spacy version with the spacytextblob. I was using spacy 2.3.7, so I downgraded my spacytextblob to a lower version using

```
pip install spacytextblob==0.1.7
```